# Visualization for rolling percentage for accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way to visualize the results below?

```
29% of the results has accuracy >= 90%
59% of the results has accuracy >= 80%
88% of the results has accuracy >= 70%
98% of the results has accuracy >= 60%
2 entries with 59% and 57%
```

Below is the code with `test result` (accuracy) and rolling percentage

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'Test Results': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 11: 1.0, 12: 1.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 1.0, 15: 1.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 1.0, 20: 0.9452757159999999, 21: 0.9450125009999999, 22: 0.941873717, 23: 0.9336287990000001, 24: 0.932937845, 25: 0.928728552, 26: 0.9217334709999999, 27: 0.9212251640000001, 28: 0.903416839, 29: 0.900519655, 30: 0.8946950090000001, 31: 0.894315668, 32: 0.893705918, 33: 0.8911087870000001, 34: 0.88341769, 35: 0.875316697, 36: 0.873369453, 37: 0.8724485759999999, 38: 0.870855835, 39: 0.8682100159999999, 40: 0.866413987, 41: 0.866225758, 42: 0.86607366, 43: 0.861137576, 44: 0.8570423090000001, 45: 0.855989443, 46: 0.8363952240000001, 47: 0.835153771, 48: 0.831573322, 49: 0.8297349890000001, 50: 0.827174152, 51: 0.82533598, 52: 0.8244730259999999, 53: 0.8231749909999999, 54: 0.821542323, 55: 0.81994456, 56: 0.8193151340000001, 57: 0.817544275, 58: 0.8043684740000001, 59: 0.804280654, 60: 0.804033467, 61: 0.8024588559999999, 62: 0.799949648, 63: 0.7998811370000001, 64: 0.7993836879999999, 65: 0.7978083340000001, 66: 0.794987453, 67: 0.7942367459999999, 68: 0.788060922, 69: 0.7833455859999999, 70: 0.783237411, 71: 0.781810415, 72: 0.77947656, 73: 0.775430937, 74: 0.769843183, 75: 0.763548283, 76: 0.76318018, 77: 0.75891367, 78: 0.7588845790000001, 79: 0.758045414, 80: 0.7545263740000001, 81: 0.7514679670000001, 82: 0.74697755, 83: 0.74597623, 84: 0.743042806, 85: 0.740900129, 86: 0.740844543, 87: 0.7246525220000001, 88: 0.7133019070000001, 89: 0.7124335999999999, 90: 0.703856728, 91: 0.694475843, 92: 0.68836286, 93: 0.683978596, 94: 0.679002735, 95: 0.664945699, 96: 0.662761826, 97: 0.649950991, 98: 0.638550239, 99: 0.60593566, 100: 0.603891537, 101: 0.602900777, 102: 0.594660442, 103: 0.565978017}, 'Rolling Percentage': {0: 0.009615385, 1: 0.019230768999999998, 2: 0.028846154, 3: 0.038461537999999997, 4: 0.048076923, 5: 0.057692308, 6: 0.067307692, 7: 0.076923077, 8: 0.086538462, 9: 0.096153846, 10: 0.10576923099999999, 11: 0.115384615, 12: 0.125, 13: 0.134615385, 14: 0.144230769, 15: 0.153846154, 16: 0.16346153800000002, 17: 0.173076923, 18: 0.182692308, 19: 0.192307692, 20: 0.201923077, 21: 0.21153846199999998, 22: 0.22115384600000002, 23: 0.23076923100000002, 24: 0.240384615, 25: 0.25, 26: 0.259615385, 27: 0.269230769, 28: 0.278846154, 29: 0.288461538, 30: 0.298076923, 31: 0.307692308, 32: 0.317307692, 33: 0.326923077, 34: 0.33653846200000004, 35: 0.346153846, 36: 0.355769231, 37: 0.365384615, 38: 0.375, 39: 0.384615385, 40: 0.394230769, 41: 0.403846154, 42: 0.41346153799999996, 43: 0.423076923, 44: 0.43269230799999997, 45: 0.44230769200000003, 46: 0.451923077, 47: 0.46153846200000004, 48: 0.471153846, 49: 0.480769231, 50: 0.490384615, 51: 0.5, 52: 0.509615385, 53: 0.519230769, 54: 0.528846154, 55: 0.538461538, 56: 0.548076923, 57: 0.557692308, 58: 0.567307692, 59: 0.576923077, 60: 0.586538462, 61: 0.596153846, 62: 0.605769231, 63: 0.615384615, 64: 0.625, 65: 0.634615385, 66: 0.644230769, 67: 0.653846154, 68: 0.663461538, 69: 0.673076923, 70: 0.682692308, 71: 0.692307692, 72: 0.701923077, 73: 0.711538462, 74: 0.721153846, 75: 0.7307692309999999, 76: 0.740384615, 77: 0.75, 78: 0.759615385, 79: 0.7692307690000001, 80: 0.778846154, 81: 0.788461538, 82: 0.798076923, 83: 0.807692308, 84: 0.817307692, 85: 0.826923077, 86: 0.836538462, 87: 0.846153846, 88: 0.8557692309999999, 89: 0.865384615, 90: 0.875, 91: 0.884615385, 92: 0.8942307690000001, 93: 0.903846154, 94: 0.913461538, 95: 0.923076923, 96: 0.932692308, 97: 0.942307692, 98: 0.951923077, 99: 0.961538462, 100: 0.971153846, 101: 0.9807692309999999, 102: 0.990384615, 103: 1.0}} )
```

Comment: You can do it with a bar chart, please show an example of a dataframe to get the graph

Comment: @ansev I have included the example dataframe